# How to embed a reactive Youtube player like the one used on Facebook in a web application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, video, youtube

I need to create a reactive video player, similar to the one found on Facebook. Meaning that, at first, no `<iframe>` or `<video>` is loaded, just an `<img>` and a description of the video you're about to watch. (see picture)

> [image: Video player "inactive"]

Then, when you click the link, the actual Youtube embeddable player shows up and the video starts.

> [image]

This makes loading your web page far more quicker. I could workaround this using Ajax and hard work, but I would prefer a solid Javascript solution or a third party lib that I could rely on.

Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

So you'll need to dynamically create an iframe element (or similar) with jQuery when you click on the image. This is a very basic example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').click(function(){
    $('<iframe>').attr({
      src: 'http://google.com'
    }).insertAfter($(this));
  });
});
```

Comment: I really like the simple Javascript solution since it's almost instantaneous. I'll wait for more answers before accepting one.

Comment: Another option too would be to have the iframe or embed already loaded on the page and hidden, then use a similar click event to .fadeIn() or something like that. The first option would be a quicker load time initially, the second would allow the video to buffer before the user decides to view it.